# Dependencies inside war-package vs. shared libraries

Tags: java, deployment, maven, shared-libraries

Typically, dependencies are bundled inside Java .war-packages.

However, one could also drop the dependencies into shared libraries, to use the same dependencies for each of the deployed artifacts.

**The question:** what are the benefits and drawbacks of each approach? In which situations would you use them?

The biggest requirement is intuitiveness/maintainability. I don't care too much about memory consumption, disk space usage, bandwith, etc. as those are cheap to buy.

Anyway, some points for each:

Including dependencies inside WAR:

- "De facto" approach(?)
- Easy to maintain (needs less configuration & scripting, etc.)
- Easy to deploy to app server
- Each module can define specific versions on libraries
- Reduces risk for classloading errors?

Using shared libraries:

- Reduced memory consumption (trivial?)
- WAR deployments can access the same instances/variables etc. as they share the classpath? It actually sounds really bad? (does it really work that way, or are they run in separate contexts, just using the same physical files?)
- Makes doing distributions and deployments more difficult as dependencies have to be separately maintained/deployed
- Packages are smaller in size (trivial)
- Dependencies can up upgraded without actual re-deployment of WAR apps (what's the benefit, really..)

Of course, we could use the best aspects of both approaches and just provide the common libraries as a shared lib, and include version specialities inside WARs. However, this doubles the maintenance effort and feels like a no-no.

Currently I'm using Glassfish 3.1.1, but this question is really app server agnostic.

Comment: Interesting, seems like I have to read the FAQ in more detail. I thought I posed two strict questions - asking what's good and in which contexts to pick either approach, considering intuitiveness/maintainability. I didn't ask generally which one is better - that's up for everyone to decide themselves, based on the facts given. I even gave a good starting point to expand from and actually got constructive answers.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your operations. If you deploy your application on your server and there is very limited number of such servers (e.g. integration, QA, production) and you have lots of dependencies you *can* put the dependencies to shared library.

If you are going to send the war to third party user that has to deploy this war on his server  it is very annoying. The poor user has to install all required dependencies (and dependencies of dependencies) in his shared library.

If you have to install your application on server that is not yours or server that has to run several enterprise application you just cannot use this method. You have to pack all your dependencies into your war file. Otherwise conflicts are inevitable.

Comment: True, although even with 1 server I would probably stick to bundling dependencies with wars. It's just so much simpler and hassle-free...

Answer (score 1):

Given your pro/con list above, it looks to me like you've already answered your question.  As you say, memory/disk is easy to come by.  Time, on the other hand, is not so easy to come by.  Putting the dependencies in WEB-INF/lib is proven, easy, and keeps your apps from having strange interaction with others or with the system class loader.  If it ain't broke...

Answer (score 1):

The advantages are as you said - each application is self-contained, i.e. you do not need upgrade a library in all deployed applications at once. Plus  only classpath collisions you should expect are when the same library is in container and the application - I dn not recall it well and classloading can differ in various containers.

If you mean by "WAR deployments" various applications, do not expect sharing anything - these are by design isolated. Shared dependencies can be upgraded separately on disk but again when and how it happens depends on container's classloaders.

So the advice is: keep with standard approach, only check the WARs/JARs you build for unnecessary dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying about classloaders. Sounds like bundled WARs are winning the war here :)